Message sent to RabbitMQ exchange is not passed to the bound queue
I'm new to message brokers and feel quite confused. The task is to send changes from PostgreSQL table to a RabbitMQ as a no-code solution. The instrument chosen is pg-bifrost. I took a look at the code and it seems the only type of exchange supported is topic. This instrument requires exchange name (not a queue name or routing key).  Using whitelist parameter I chose a single postgres table to publish changes.
I created exchange called ex, created a queue called test and bound them.
When I make some change in the table pg-bifrost log reacts with the following:
time="2024-09-24T14:44:08Z" level=info msg="Waiting for desired confirms count" desiredCount=2 id=0 package=rabbitmq routine=transporter. The desired count increments with every change in Postgres table.
and on the only channel page I see a peak of unroutable messages
What I expect is message directed to the bound queue but this does not happen.
Maybe someone could point me to a different no-code solution rather than pg-bifrost. Any help would be appreciated.

Hi, seeing your message late, but if you haven't resolved it, the cause was the routing key you used to bind exchange to queue. You should use # and not *.

@Olivier hello there! Thanks for helping me on this one. After creating a new binding with # as a routing key messages are successfully passed to the queue!
